# How to show submenu which contains specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have menu with submenu like this.

```
<ul>
 <li><a>First item</a></li>
 <li><a>Second item</a></li>
 <li><a>Third item</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="current_page_item"><a>First sub item</a></li>
    <li><a>Second sub item</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a>Forth item</a>
   <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="other_class"><a>First sub item</a></li>
    <li><a>Second sub item</a></li>
  </ul>

 </li>
</ul>
```

Submenu is hide with jQuery:

```
jQuery('ul.sub-menu').hide();
```

How can I select and show submenu which contains `li` element with class `current_page_item`. ?

This is not working:

```
jQuery('ul.sub-menu > .current_page_item a').show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I select and show submenu which contains li element with class
>   current_page_item. ?

You can do it by using `:has()` selector,

```
jQuery('ul.sub-menu:has(li.other_class)').show();
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/huwxLoym/)

Answer (score 0):

this worked also:

```
jQuery('ul.sub-menu > .current_page_item').parent().show();
```